# why i am getting error while implementingInterThread Communication in java using wait and notify?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am implementing a simple example of SimpleInterThreadCommunication and have used wait and notify.

I am getting an error on total in InterThread class can anyone explain why

```
public class InterThread 

{

public static void main(String s[])throws InterruptedException

{

    Thread b=new Thread();

    b.start();

    Thread.sleep(10);

    synchronized (b) 

    {

    System.out.println("Main thread trying to call wait");

    b.wait();

    System.out.println("Main thread got notifies");

    System.out.println(b.total); //error here total cannot be resolved to a field

   }

 }

}

class ThreadB extends InterThread

{

    int total=0;

    public void run()

    {

        synchronized(this)

        {

            System.out.println("child thread got notifies");

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)

            {

                total=total+i;

            }

            System.out.println("child thread ready to give  notification");

              this.notify();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Its because your object b is of thread class and total field is not defined implicitly in the thread class, instead you have defined variable b in ThreadB class. Hence it cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Because `Thread` doesn't have a `public` field called `b`.

Comment: btw. Thread communication can be done in a simpler and more reliable way with the classes in java.util.concurrent. e.g. LinkedTransferQueue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Object of `ThreadB` class then you can access total field.
it is not visible to `Thread` class object.

You have created `b` object Of `Thread` class and in `Thread` class no any such field named as `total` available.

change your code something like below:

```
    ThreadB b1=new ThreadB();
    System.out.println(b1.total);
```

Comment: Why i am not getting total as output now My Output:child thread got notifies
child thread ready to give  notification
Main thread trying to call wait

Comment: you need to change your sequence of notify and wait. you are calling notify first then wait instead this it should be vice-versa. because if one thread is going on wait then some other thread should notify it. if no other thread will call notify then your thread will might wait forever that is why after calling `wait()` nothing is happend

Answer (score 0):

Answer i made changes after suggestion from helpful people 
Here is the corrected code

public class InterThread

{

public static void main(String s[])throws InterruptedException

{

```
ThreadB b=new ThreadB(); //correction 1

b.start();

Thread.sleep(10);

synchronized (b) 

{

  System.out.println("Main thread trying to call wait");

  b.notify();  //correction2

  System.out.println("Main thread got notifies");

System.out.println(b.total);
```

}

}

}

class ThreadB extends InterThread

{

```
int total=0;

public void run()

{

    synchronized(this)

    {

        System.out.println("child thread got notifies");

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)

        {

            total=total+i;

        }

        System.out.println("child thread ready to give  notification");

    try

       {

        System.out.println("child thread ready trying to call wait");

        this.wait(); //corrected 3

       }

        catch(InterruptedException e)

        {

            System.out.println("interrupted Exception");

        }

   }

}
```

}